# Column name incorrect after create table

Tags: ucanaccess

See here: https://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/bugs/155/

I don't know where the bug is. They say it's a ucanaccess issue.

Comment: Yeah, the bug is plain to see in ucanaccess (it does a regex replacement on the whole body of a `create table`, and it *tries* to protect column names, but does a rather poor job of it), but what do you hope to accomplish by asking here?

Comment: @hobbs I don't see where to report bugs for ucanaccess.  I worked around it but I would like it to be reported so it can fixed at some point.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/

Comment: OK thanks, I'll post there.